# Error : No exports were found that match the constraint:

Tags: c#, attributes, mef, waf

I'm building an WAF project. When i debug my project. I'm encounted this problem

```
"The composition produced a single composition error. The root cause is provided below.
 Review the CompositionException.Errors property for more detailed information.\r\n\r\n1) 
 No exports were found that match the constraint: \n\tContractName\tWaf.InformationManager.OneNote.Modules.Applications.Views.INoteView\n\t
 RequiredTypeIdentity\tWaf.InformationManager.OneNote.Modules.Applications.Views.INoteView\r\n"
```

How do i slove this ?

I sloved my problem ( Thanks to **sgrassie** )
I didn't create an NoteView.xaml ( which implements INoteView and add [Export(typeof(INoteView)] at class header )

Comment: If I've answered your question, you should mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an `[Export(typeof(INoteView)]` attribute on the class which implements `INoteView`.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks bro. It work. I didn't create an NoteView.xaml ( which implements INoteView and of course [Export(typeof(INoteView)] at class header ). I will update my question belove the question

Comment: For the last 3 days I was struggling with this problem. You are my savior. Thanks a lot :)